# How do I with Grunt modify code within a javscript.js file?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, frontend

my development code has:

```
  var element1 = document.createElement("script");
  element1.src = "js/file1.js";
  document.body.appendChild(element1);

  var element2 = document.createElement("script");
  element2.src = "js/file2.js";
  document.body.appendChild(element2);
```

after i run grunt i want to modify the above code for my production code to display as this:

```
  var element1 = document.createElement("script");
  element1.src = "js/file3.concat.min.js";
  document.body.appendChild(element1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace

matched `js/file2.js` replace it with `js/file3.concat.min.js` and so that it wouldn't append `js/file2.js` i replaced the line `document.body.appendChild(element2);` with `""`